# Can an exception be handled in another class, assembly, or abstract class?

Tags: c#, exception, dll, stack, stack-trace

I see the need to copy and paste the following error handling code several times.  What are my options when working within a Catch statement?

- In doing so, will I lose valuable information in the process?  (example: are exceptions re-wrapped in another exception, or loss of stack information)
- How can someone tell the difference between a "throw" in myAbstractClass and one in the Select method below?

Here is sample code I want to replicate

```
public class StackUserDataSource : AbstractEnhancedTableDataSource<StackUserDataServiceContext>
{
  //.. stuff

 public IEnumerable<StackUserDataModel> Select() 
    {
        try
        {
            var results = from c in _ServiceContext.StackUserTable
                          select c;

            var query = results.AsTableServiceQuery();
            var queryResults = query.Execute();

            return queryResults;
        }
        catch (StorageClientException e)
        {

           // Todo: consider sticking this in another central location    
            switch (e.ErrorCode)
            {
                case StorageErrorCode.AccessDenied:
                    break;
                case StorageErrorCode.AccountNotFound:
                    break;
                case StorageErrorCode.AuthenticationFailure:
                    break;
                // ... Yadda yadda, handle some exceptions, not others.. this is a demo.
                case StorageErrorCode.TransportError:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            throw;
        }
    }
```

**Update**:

I doubt this is possible, but can I dynamically catch and filter exceptions in an external library?  The concept goes like this

```
        try
        {
            var results = from c in _ServiceContext.StackUserTable
                          select c;

            var query = results.AsTableServiceQuery();
            var queryResults = query.Execute();

            return queryResults;
        }
        catch (MyExternalExceptionHelperDLL e)
        {
            // all exceptions referenced in MyExternalHelper are passed below
            MyExternalExceptionHelper.ProcessException(e);
         }
         catch (exception)
        {
         }
```

Since it's probably not possible for the MyExternalExceptionHelperDLL to dynamically pick and choose what to listen for (i.e. SQL, vs Networking vs File, but not authentication)

```
        try
        {
            var results = from c in _ServiceContext.StackUserTable
                          select c;

            var query = results.AsTableServiceQuery();
            var queryResults = query.Execute();

            return queryResults;
        }
         catch (exception e)
        {
           MyExternalExceptionHelper.ProcessException(e);

           // The problem is that I don't know how to catch exceptions thrown from that static method above,
           // or how to override that exception handling...
        }
```

But with the above code, its not clear to me how the end user can opt into or override my methods of event handling.

Comment: You can call a helper method in a `catch` block just like anywhere else...

Comment: Is there a reason that long `switch` statement does nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this. The important part is that the `throw` needs to be in the original `catch` block in order to preserve the stack trace.

```
public IEnumerable<StackUserDataModel> Select() 
{
    try
    {
        ...
    }
    catch (StorageClientException e)
    {
       // You could do this if there is no fancy processing to do
       if (!IsCatchableException(e))
          throw;
    }
}

bool IsCatchableException(StorageClientException e)
{
    ... optionally do some fancy processing of the exception, e.g. logging....
    switch (e.ErrorCode)
    {
        case StorageErrorCode.AccessDenied:
        case StorageErrorCode.AccountNotFound:
        ....
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want the consumer of my class to override my exception handling.  Would it be wise to make `IsCatchableException` be invoked in the `catch (Exception e)` section, and then let my app figure out if the exception applies to it?  Idea being that the user can always implement `catch (SpecialException abc)` and my code will never see that.

Answer (score 1):

You can only invoke `throw;` directly inside a `catch` clause, while `throw e;` can be invoked at any point where you have an exception instance `e`. The difference between them is that `throw;` rethrows the exception while keeping its original stack trace intact, while `throw e;` resets the stack trace so that it appears that the exception was originally thrown by `throw e;` - which could be quite annoying when debugging. So I suggest that you extract the `switch` statement to a separate method that takes a `StorageClientException` as a parameter, but keep `throw;` directly in the `catch` clause.

Comment: So is a proper implementation of  `ProcessException(e);` such that it returns a bool and the the throw occurs in that exact method, versus my DLL?